# добавить и сохранить данные из textbox в dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Имеется 4 текстбокса. Текст из них при нажатии на кнопку "добавить" нужно добавить в datagridview. При этом эти данные должные сохраниться и в базе данных.

```
 string sql = "INSERT INTO words_Table(id,word,translation,dictionary) VALUES(@id,word,@translation, @dictionary)";
               cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@translation",transl);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dictionary", textBox1.Text);
               con.Open();
               con.Close();
               retrieve();
 private void retrieve()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM words_Table ";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                //LOOP THRU DT
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    populate(int.Parse(row[0].ToString()), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString());
                }
                con.Close();
                //CLEAR DT
                dt.Rows.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                con.Close();
            }
}
```

Однако выдает ошибку: Невозможно очистить этот список.

Comment: Вероятно, к датагриду сделана привязка коллекции или дататейбла. Вот эту коллекцию или дататейбл и нужно очищать.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста больше кода. У вас не описаны метод populate, переменная dt и вообще неясно как происходит само добавление данных - sql запрос есть, а действий с ним нет.